# How to click a button with Selenium that don't exist at browser.page_source

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I would like to click the button **Alle akzeptieren**. Unfortunately when I search in the print(browser.page_source) I don't find it. A `WebDriverWait(browser, 10)` did not help.

My code:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')

browser.get("https://www.finanzen.net/")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class_='message-component message-button no-children button-responsive-primary']").click()
```

[image]

greetings from Ingolstadt

Comment: Post the `html` not an image of the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the button and the "popup" itself is inside the `iframe`:

[image: frame]

You'd need to [switch to it](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to) prior to finding and clicking the button:

```
# switch to frame
frame = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[id^=sp_message_iframe]")
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)

# click the button
button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.message-button.button-responsive-primary")
button.click()

# switch back to the default context
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

---

Note that you may need to [explicitly wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) for the frame to appear to allow the page time to load and show the dialog in the frame:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='./geckodriver')
browser.get("https://www.finanzen.net/")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

# switch to frame
frame = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id^=sp_message_iframe]"))
)
browser.switch_to.frame(frame)

# click the button
button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button.message-button.button-responsive-primary")
button.click()

# switch back to the default context
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element <kbd>Alle akzeptieren</kbd> is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.finanzen.net/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[id^='sp_message_iframe'][src^='https://consent.finanzen.net/index.html']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[title='Alle akzeptieren']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://www.finanzen.net/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@id, 'sp_message_iframe') and starts-with(@src, 'https://consent.finanzen.net/index.html')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Alle akzeptieren']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)